# Sync data (blk.dat) only with bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, block

The purpose is to sync the all the blk data into local computer for analyzing.

Is that possible to sync data (blk.dat) only with bitcoind?

Or is there any other solution available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncing with Bitcoin Core (bitcoind) is efficient and secure so that is the recommended way to obtain the `blk*.dat` files. The `blk*.dat` format is specific to Bitcoin Core, so you can't use other implementations (like btcd) to do so.

If you only want to collect the data without verifying the blocks for validity, you can set the `-assumevalid=<hex>` argument to a recent block so that the entire chain up until that point is assumed to be valid (as the name suggests).

What's more, you can use the `-blocksonly` parameter to ignore transactions from peers that aren't in blocks, so your node will focus only on the blocks themselves.

Comment: Per my understanding, bitcoind is pretty heavy and cost many resources, is there any lightweight solution?

Comment: @Carpemer I've added some flags to the answer that might help achieve what you are looking for. Of course downloading the blockchain will still be time consuming and require a lot of bandwidth because of its size, but there is no way to avoid that if you want to download the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks, that is exact what I need!

Comment: Added 
assumevalid=00000000000000000002b276368619e6867fb285b02162df27eb85c08189776b into the conf file, the speed seems don't have very big change.

Comment: Is your download speed fast? Remember you are still downloading around 380 GB.

Comment: I use 500M network, what is the expectation in general case?

Comment: Depends on your computer specs too. You can increase speed further using `-dbcache=4000` (or as high as you like based on the amount of memory) startup parameter.